# Convert date into days

Tags: java, date, kotlin, converters

How to convert below format date into **minutes**, **hrs**, **days**, **weeks**. Generally using this info to display message posted information.

**2020-04-11T17:41:00Z**

Comment: What do you mean in minutes and etc.? You want to fetch part of date or date in particular unit?

Comment: There are many posts here that answer your question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion/).

Comment: i want to display like this.........If the date is 15 min ago to current time...i have to display "15min ago"...if the date 1 day ago...i have to display "1 day ago".

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.parse(data).get(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH)`

Comment: Welcome to SO community, what are the T and 00Z ?

Comment: @Zain The format is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which defines `T` and `Z` and everything in the string.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks bro :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not so clear. So, I'm writing here some sample code for your understanding. As you can see in this example and you will further explore, **java.time.** and **java.time.format.** are quite rich with classes related to date and time. Avoid using the [outdated java.util.* date and time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html).

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "2020-04-11T17:41:00";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
        System.out.println("Year: " + dateTime.getYear());
        System.out.println("Month: " + dateTime.getMonthValue());
        System.out.println("Day: " + dateTime.getDayOfMonth());
        System.out.println("Hour: " + dateTime.getHour());
        System.out.println("Minute: " + dateTime.getMinute());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Year: 2020
Month: 4
Day: 11
Hour: 17
Minute: 41
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean, so I will work with this premise. A string in this format is inputted: 2020-04-11T17:41:00Z. As for what you mean to convert it to minutes, hours, etc. I am assuming to make it to a date object? Please correct me if I am wrong

*Small tip: If you are the one in control of the date format, before it is turned to this string, I would recommend you use Unix time (A.K.A. POSIX time - read about it online).*

If my interpretation is correct, you can use SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ");
Date dt = sdf.parse(string);
```

You can also use `sdf` to convert your date object into your given format with:

```
sdf.format(YourDateObject)
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Also your code throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'T'`.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using the Joda Time library, it's a popular one and many people are using it because of it's simplicity.

It has custom types for what you need. [Joda Website](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Example code from their website:

```java
public boolean isAfterPayDay(DateTime datetime) {
  if (datetime.getMonthOfYear() == 2) {   // February is month 2!!
    return datetime.getDayOfMonth() > 26;
  }
  return datetime.getDayOfMonth() > 28;
}
```

Comment: Since most of the functionality of Joda Time was added into Java 8, the Joda Time web site recommends migtating to that.  (As I understand it, It's likely to be much more standard, guaranteed to be available without adding any dependencies, and so a better option for most purposes.)